# converting a function that gets arry of chars to function that gets char *

Tags: c, char

I'm really new to programming in C and I'm a little bit stuck on something for an assignment in my course and hope someone can help :)

I have written a very simple function that checks if there are any double commas in a string.
I have written it as a function that gets an array of chars but I need the function to get char* instead.

I am struggling to convert it and would appreciate any help I can get to work this out.

```
int findDoubleComma(char a[])
{
    int comma=0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<128;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==" ")
            continue;
        if(a[i]!=",")
        {
            comma=0;
            i++;
        }
        else
            if(comma==1)
                return -100;
            else
            {
                comma=1;
                i++;
            }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function didn't work for me. I changed implementation:

```
int findDoubleComma(char a[])
{
    int comma = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == ',')
        {
            if (1 == comma)
            {
                return -100;
            }
            else
            {
                comma = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            comma = 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Actually, when function receives array of characters, C language automatically translates it to pointer of char type. So you can pass to such function also pointer and it will work.
But if you need function with signature that receives pointer, you can use another function that will work as a wrapper:

```
int findDoubleCommaPOINTER(char *a)
{
    return findDoubleComma(a);
}
```

Moreover, you can just change the signature of your function from

```
int findDoubleComma(char a[])
```

to

```
int findDoubleComma(char *a)
```

without changing code, and it will work.